# ¿Es posible enviar variables a dos paginas diferentes con un a href?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenia una pregunta con un boton href , es posible enviar variables a dos archivos diferentes? por ejemplo enviar al agregar.php y enviarlo tambien al eliminar.php
Por ejemplo algo asi :

```
 <a href="eliminar.php&&agregar.php?variable=<?php valor a enviar ?>"
```

Resulta que necesito que al insertar un registro por ejemplo el id autoincrementable esta asi : 1.2.3.4.5 y yo elimino el registro 5 y si inserto nuevamente un registro no me salte a 6 si no que me agregue en el id 5 , ya que tiene que ser consecutivo e intento enviarlo a otro archivo para poder hacer la validacion, me ayudarían muchisimo! Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Soy consciente que esto puede conflictuar ya que lo envió a dos paginas diferentes  o no se si hay otro metodo para lo que intento hacer !

Comment: El atributo href realmente no envía nada. Sólo redirige tu cliente siguiendo el valor dado a forma de hipervínculo. Que tu cliente (navegador) le entregue unos parámetros y cookies al PHP que pones ahí, eso es otra cosa. Para recibir mejor ayuda, incluye el código relevante en esos scripts PHP

Comment: Lo que necesitas es distinto porque como referencia @Alfabravo solamente se envia la variable al nuevo link para recepcionarla en post o get, segun entiendo no es que todas las lineas se agreguen y eliminen a la vez, segun la propuesta deberias obtener el ultimo registro y con ello trabajar como mas te convenga.  por ejemplo $idCaso=$pdo->lastInsertId(); se obtiene el ultimo registro si es $pdo

Comment: Eso debes hacerlo desde dentro de un archivo PHP, no se pueden ejecutar dos scripts en una petición GET a la vez. Pero si puedes, desde un script en PHP, realizar los includes necesarios de esos scripts para realizar las acciones que harian por separado si fueran llamados uno a uno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es posible con una etiqueta `href`

Pero si lo es con JavaScript:

1. tendrías que habilitar las ventanas emergentes.
2. implementar un mecanismo de atributos tipo `data-` que te permita leer los datos y las variables que deseas utilizar.

***Nota:*** aquí en SOes no va a funcionar por que se supone que esta contenido en un sandbox.

> Blocked opening 'https://stacksnippets.net/www.google.com' in a new
> window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose
> 'allow-popups' permission is not set

```js
function openInNewTab(url) {
 window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

  console.log('document ready')
  
  let idElement = 'link';
  let eventListener = 'click';
  
  document.getElementById(idElement).addEventListener(eventListener, function(event) {
    
    console.log('Click Element');
    
    let linkList = event.target.getAttribute("data-target");
    let linkarray = linkList.split(",");
    let value = event.target.getAttribute("data-value");
    
    linkarray.forEach(function(url) {
      console.log(url+value);
      window.open(url+value, '_blank');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link" data-target="www.google.com,www.youtube.com" data-value="?variable=<?php valor a enviar ?>">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks amigo!!!